# Ajax запрос работает не коректно

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Вроде как при скролле он подгружает нужные мне записи, но почему то делает это по разному. Бывает как надо, а бывает дублирует очень много раз одно и тоже, бывает на большом мониторе вроде нормально, а на маленьком тоже бывает повторяет или дублирует . Мне кажется какая та проблема с высотой и тд. Помогите, пожалуйста

Мой Js

```
jQuery(window).on('scroll', onScroll); 


function onScroll(){ 

  if (jQuery(window).scrollTop()   + jQuery(window).height()  > jQuery(document).height()) {
    
        var data = {
            'action': 'load_posts_by_ajax1',
            'page': page,
            'security1': blog1.security1
        };
 
        jQuery.post(blog1.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
            if(jQuery.trim(response) != '') {
                jQuery('.blog-posts1').append(response);
                  page++;
            } else {
                jQuery('.loadmore1').hide();
            }
        });
    }



}
```

custom template

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'portfolio',
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => '3',
    'paged' => 1,
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>

<?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : 
    <div class="blog-posts1">
        <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); 
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Show</a>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>     
<?php endif; ?>





function load_posts_by_ajax_callback() {
 check_ajax_referer('load_more_posts', 'security');
$paged = $_POST['page'];
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'portfolio',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => '3',
    'paged' => $paged,
);
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    ?>
    
    <?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : 
        <div class="blog-posts1">
            <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); 
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Show</a>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div>     
    <?php endif; wp_die(); ?>
}

add_action('wp_ajax_load_posts_by_ajax1', 'load_posts_by_ajax_callback1');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_load_posts_by_ajax1','load_posts_by_ajax_callback1);
```

Comment: да, как и сказали в ответе, нужен флаг - идет загрузка или нет.  Если вы в функции onScroll() напишете `console.log('test'); ` , то увидите, что она запускается много раз при малейшем скролле. И все эти запуски - у вас запросы к серверу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто добавьте ещё переменную isLoading и проверяйте её перед вызовом post если не isLoading то установите на true а в callback меняйте isLoading на false